# Prologue and epilogue in python logger

Tags: python, logging

I wish to create a logger class that upon the first logging.getLogger() will write a prologue and once the process ends the logger with write an epilogue

my code:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('name')
logger.info('HI')
```

The expected output:

```
2014-09-29 10:50:40,187 - INFO - ** My prologue **
2014-09-29 10:50:40,187 - INFO - HI
2014-09-29 10:50:40,187 - INFO - ** My epilogue **
```

Comment: User formatters to gain your logging format

Comment: @Serj are you clear that he wants the prolog and epilog once only per logger, not on a per message basis?   AIUI, formatters are per message things....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As observed, the epiLoggers in my previous answers are not "singletons", and have to be passed around between modules that are going to use them.

Options for getting around this include

- subclassing logger.Logger (if that is in fact possible, which I have not investigated),
- implementing a mechanism to create and store and retrive epiLoggers like logger.getLogger (ridiculously overblown idea)
- creating a singleton-like epiLogger that can be used in multiple modules.

This solution does the latter.

```
import logging

class epiLogger():
    _initialised = {}
    _finalised = {}

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(name)
        self.name = name
        if not epiLogger._initialised.get(name):
            self.logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
            self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
            self.logger.info('** My Prologue **')
            epiLogger._initialised[self.name] = True

    def info(self, the_info):
        self.logger.info(the_info)

    def __del__(self):
        if not self.__class__._finalised.get(self.name):
            self.logger.info('** My Epilogue **')
            self.__class__._finalised[self.name] = True

a = epiLogger("foo")

a.info("foo!")
a.info("bar!")
a.info("party!")
```

I know that this feels like a good thing to do, but read here: http://jalf.dk/blog/2010/03/singletons-solving-problems-you-didnt-know-you-never-had-since-1995/.  I would seriously ask yourself "actually, might it be best in the long run to pass each epiLogger around to where it belongs?"

Or of course [investigate subclassing logger.Logger](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/691963) :)

Comment: I have tried this, for some reason it does't always log the epilogue. I did like the link about singletons though and decided to take the problem to a different approach

Comment: Not sure yet why that would be, but I coded this quickly, with a light test only.  I may tinker around out of curiousity when I get a moment.  Most of my python is building wx apps, and I explicitly pass my logger around to the views & controller.

Comment: With expert help (http://stackoverflow.com/a/26119248/554807) I think I've found what would give you strife, and edited accordingly. I tested it more thoroughly (mutliple files, multiple loggers).  I'd be keen to know if it works in your situation.  Even though now the code is even more spooky :)  That's singletons for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brute force, simplistic implementation.

Note that any logging.Logger methods you want to call on the epiLogger need to be implemented: I've only implemented info().

```
import logging

# class definition for the new logger that does the pro and epilogues

class epiLogger():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(name)
        self.logger.info('** My Prologue **')

    def info(self, the_info):
        self.logger.info(the_info)

    def __del__(self):
        self.logger.info('** My Epilogue **')

# preamble to set up the underlying logger that it needs
# ... could be inside the class constructor, depending on whether the class
# is supposed to be "encapsulating and providing"  or "using" this external one

the_logger = logging.getLogger("foo")
the_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

the_logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())

# using the good stuff...

a = epiLogger("foo")

a.info("foo!")
a.info("bar!")
a.info("party!")
```

produces:

```
~ mgregory$ python foo.py
** My Prologue **
foo!
bar!
party!
** My Epilogue **
~ mgregory$
```

(For simplicity I've left out the time/date formatting etc, since it's not really relevant to the question)

Comment: How would you getLogger from other modules? seems like I will have to pass the instance of epiLogger to all my modules

Comment: I added a separate answer, because this is a ... different answer :)